# Sort list with letters, numbers and special characters

Tags: python, sorting

I know this kind of question has already been asked several times but I cannot find a proper answer to my problem.

I have a list of strings containing (or not) any kind of characters, letters, numbers, and special characters (`-` or `_`).

I would like to sort this list but having the following priority criterias: letters (insensitive case, no matter if uppercase or lowercase first) first, then numbers, then special characters (I don't mind the order of special characters)

For example :

```py
>>> data = "abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_"
>>> expected = "aAbBcCdDeEfFhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ123456789-_"
>>> result = sorted(data, key=str.lower)
>>> print(result)
['-', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '_', 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E', 'f', 'F', 'h', 'H', 'i', 'I', 'j', 'J', 'k', 'K', 'l', 'L', 'm', 'M', 'n', 'N', 'o', 'O', 'p', 'P', 'q', 'Q', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S', 't', 'T', 'u', 'U', 'v', 'V', 'w', 'W', 'x', 'X', 'y', 'Y', 'z', 'Z']
>>> print(result == expected)
False
```

I tried some good algorithms from already asked questions but they never sort both number and special characters with letters.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with *"any kind of characters, letters, numbers, and special characters (- or _)"*? The *"any kind of characters"* already covers letters, numbers, and those special characters and all other characters, so that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can try to employ a Lambda to this case

```py
data = "abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_"
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: ( not x.isalpha(), not x.isnumeric(), x.lower()))
print(sorted_data)
expected = ''.join(sorted_data)
print(expected)
```

Result

```
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E', 'f', 'F', 'h', 'H', 'i', 'I', 'j', 'J', 'k', 'K', 'l', 'L', 'm', 'M', 'n', 'N', 'o', 'O', 'p', 'P', 'q', 'Q', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S', 't', 'T', 'u', 'U', 'v', 'V', 'w', 'W', 'x', 'X', 'y', 'Y', 'z', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', '_']

aAbBcCdDeEfFhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ123456789-_
```

Update : Adding the suggestion by @Goku as the expected output required which was missed.

Comment: `expected = ''.join(sorted_data)`.. +1

Comment: It is a positional sort, results depend on position of character in data. If data was `"Aabcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_"`, expected would be `AaAbBcCdDeEfFhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ123456789-_`

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
def custom_key(char):
    if char.isalpha():
        return (1, char.lower(), char)
    elif char.isdigit():
        return (2, char)
    else:
        return (3, char)

data = "abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_"
data_list = list(data)
sorted_data = ''.join(sorted(data_list, key=custom_key))
```

Based on the numbers, the characters will be sorted:

- 1 for lowercase and capital (lowercase first)
- 2 for digits
- 3 for special

Comment: Hi. Simple and efficient, great! I would call the first function `custom_key` rather than `custom_sort`, since it's just a key, not a sorting function.

Comment: Agreed! Will change the name of the function.

Comment: `custom_key` will result in uppercase sorted before lowercase characters, the OP's expected order was the opposite, lower before upper. This can be achieved by changing the third line of `custom_key` to `return (1, char.lower(), char.swapcase())`. Although this will not work for all Latin lower/uppercase pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide an alternative, and more flexible solution, using **PyICU**. With **PyICU**.

1. Create an PyICU Locale object
2. Create a collator instance
3. Use the collator sort keys to sort a list

For this instance, I will use a BCP-47 language tag to use the CLDR Root Collation Algorithm and tailor the algorithm.

The language tag `und` is an *undetermined* language, and is the BCP-47 language tag used to specify the *root* collation. You could also use any language tag that uses the root collation unmodified, like `en`.  Alternatively you could use a tailored collation to sort by French collation. To tailor the collation, I am using Unicode's **U** extension for BCP-47 with the `kr` subtag  enables reordering collation sequences. The subtags `-u-kr-Latn-digit-punct` will allow us to sort Latin script content first, then digits, then punctuation, then everything else.

The `kr` subtag will allow you to control the order of collation sequences by script, it also allows you to control order of sorting of whitespace, punctuation, symbols, currency symbols, and digits.

```py
import icu
locale = icu.Locale.forLanguageTag('und-u-kr-Latn-digit-punct')
collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(locale)
sorted_data = sorted(list(data), key=collator.getSortKey)
expected = "".join(sorted_data)
print(expected)
# aAbBcCdDeEfFhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ123456789_-
```

If you want uppercase sorted before lowercase, modify the language tag to `-u-kr-Latn-digit-punct-kf-upper`, where the `kf` subtag is used to specify the order of case.

```py
locale = icu.Locale.forLanguageTag('und-u-kr-Latn-digit-punct-kf-upper')
collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(locale)
sorted_data = sorted(list(data), key=collator.getSortKey)
expected = "".join(sorted_data)
print(expected)
# AaBbCcDdEeFfHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz123456789_-
```

Likewise, using the BCP-47 language tag 'de-DE-u-kr-Latn-digit-punct-kf-upper', you could sort the Latin script content according to German collation rules.